# Django + heroku - import error on line that doesn't exist

Tags: django, heroku, import, django-registration

I'm new to django (using python 2.7) and I was just trying to use heroku for the first time but I always get the following error:

```
remote: -----> Preparing static assets
remote:        Collectstatic configuration error. To debug, run:
remote:        $ heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

When I run that command, an import error regarding the django registration redux library shows up. I've had this problem before in Django and I fixed it by placing RequestSite under 'requests' and Site under 'models'. That solved the problem but the error still shows up in Heroku.

```
(venv) C:\Users\Carolina\Desktop\Coding\venv\project1>heroku run python manage.p
    y collectstatic --noinput
    Running python manage.py collectstatic --noinput on acla-acla... up, run.3645
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/_
    _init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/_
    _init__.py", line 324, in execute
        django.setup()
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", lin
    e 18, in setup
        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py"
    , line 115, in populate
        app_config.ready()
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/app
    s.py", line 22, in ready
        self.module.autodiscover()
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__i
    nit__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
        autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_load
    ing.py", line 50, in autodiscover_modules
        import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in im
    port_module
        __import__(name)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/registration/admin.py",
    line 2, in <module>
        from django.contrib.sites.models import RequestSite
    ImportError: cannot import name RequestSite
```

The thing is - that line doesn't exist. I went to venv/lib/site-packages/registration/admin.py and line 2 is this one:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.sites.requests import RequestSite    # HERE
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from registration.models import RegistrationProfile
from registration.users import UsernameField


class RegistrationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = ['activate_users', 'resend_activation_email']
    list_display = ('user', 'activation_key_expired')
    raw_id_fields = ['user']
    search_fields = ('user__{0}'.format(UsernameField()), 'user__first_name', 'user__last_name')

    def activate_users(self, request, queryset):
        """
        Activates the selected users, if they are not already
        activated.

        """
        for profile in queryset:
            RegistrationProfile.objects.activate_user(profile.activation_key)
    activate_users.short_description = _("Activate users")

    def resend_activation_email(self, request, queryset):
        """
        Re-sends activation emails for the selected users.

        Note that this will *only* send activation emails for users
        who are eligible to activate; emails will not be sent to users
        whose activation keys have expired or who have already
        activated.

        """
        if Site._meta.installed:
            site = Site.objects.get_current()
        else:
            site = RequestSite(request)

        for profile in queryset:
            if not profile.activation_key_expired():
                profile.send_activation_email(site)
    resend_activation_email.short_description = _("Re-send activation emails")


admin.site.register(RegistrationProfile, RegistrationAdmin)
```

This is what I get with pip freeze, just in case:

```
Django==1.9
django-crispy-forms==1.5.2
django-registration==2.0.3
django-registration-redux==1.2
django-tinymce==2.2.0
Pillow==3.0.0
requests==2.9.0
South==1.0.2
stripe==1.27.1
wheel==0.24.0
```

Anyone knows why this is happening? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT ----**

Ok, so the problem was the one mentioned by Daniel Roseman. The library is broken in pypi and I had to tell heroku to install it from github (where the package is fixed). 
So, I went to my requirements.txt file and replaced this line:

```
django-registration-redux==1.2
```

with this one:

```
-e git://github.com/macropin/django-registration.git#egg=django-registration==1.2
```

(I also removed 'django-registration==2.0.3' because it is an old version of django-registration-redux and was creating problems).
Hope this helps people with the same issue!

Comment: What happen when you run collectstatic in local?

Comment: With debug=False, the static files don't load (but that seemed to happen to a lot of people that were watching the same tutorial as me - I had to run python manage.py runserver --insecure for them to work). With debug=True, everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you edited the code for your locally installed copy of django-registration-redux. But that won't have any effect on Heroku, since the library will be installed directly from PyPI, according to the version in your requirements.txt.

If the library is really broken, you will need to fork it and point your requirements.txt to your fixed version. However, looking at the code on GitHub, it doesn't actually seem to be broken; you just need to update the version you are pointing to.

Comment: But I was checking the versions and django-registration-redux 1.2 seems to be the the most recent one: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-registration-redux/
That was the version I also installed locally using pip (and I had to fix it) :S